# How to use parameterless method without bracket as type parameter?

Tags: scala, generics

For example, I have 2 method definition as below with and without bracket.

```
def foo1: String = "bar"
def foo2():String = "bar"
```

In case of method parameter, I can create higher ordered functions for both as below:

```
def bar(fn: =>String) = ???  // bar(foo1)
def bar(fn: ()=>String) = ???    // bar(foo2)
```

However in case of `generic type`, I'm only able to use `foo2`.

```
val list: List[() => String] = List(foo2)
```

The following does not work.

```
val list: List[() => String] = List(foo1) //foo1 type mismatch.
val list: List[ => String] = List(foo1)   //Invalid syntax.
```

So, my question is what is the correct type definition for parameterless and bracketless method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first definition of bar `def bar(fn: => String) = ???` does not describe a function parameter with no arguments, it describes a lazy parameter.

So if you have a function which produces a string, and you wish to defer the execution of this function, you can pass it as a lazy param into your function. This allows the function `bar` in this case, to either execute the function and produce the `String`, or to pass this code to another function. Take for example an if statement, it takes in 2 functions, and only executes 1 of them based on the predicate.

Now to answer your question, you can either use the `_` symbol to turn your method into a function (eta expansion), or you can just use the lambda notation to manually make your `foo` an function.

```
def foo1 = "bar"
val list: List[() => String] = List(foo1)    // crashes since foo1 is not a fn its 
                                             // just a string    
val list: List[() => String] = List(() => foo1) // works

val foo1Eta = foo1 _
val list: List[() => String] = List(foo1Eta) // works    

val foo2 = () => "bar"
val list: List[() => String] = List(foo2)    // works

def foo3 = () => "bar"
val list: List[() => String] = List(foo3)    // also works
```

Comment: The foo2 and foo3 examples seem to be the same

Comment: @soMuchToLearnAndShare they are very similar, one uses a val and the other uses a def. The intent there was to show that this lambda fn works with both def and val.

Answer (score 1):

To pass a parameterless def as a function parameter, you need to turn it into a function. You do this with this syntax:

```
val list: List[() => String] = List(foo1 _)
```